# Формула Excel, или как выбрать группу значений

Tags: формулы, excel

Дано.

Таблица с группами расстояний:

1. | <300 км.
2. | 301-1000 км.
3. | 1001-2000 км.
4. | 2001-4000 км.
5. и т.д.

И есть значение расстояния между городами, равное **1139**.

Вопрос.

Как, используя всего одну ячейку таблицы Excel, вывести в ней значение группы, к которой относится заданное расстояние (т.е. 1,2,3,4 и т.д.)? Без использования функций "ЕСЛИ" и "ИЛИ", это слишком просто.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В одной ячейке таблицы (столбец В) разместить не диапазон расстояний, а начало диапазона.

В таком случае можно применить неточный поиск в *ПОИСКПОЗ*:

```
=ИНДЕКС(A1:A50;ПОИСКПОЗ(1139;B1:B50;1))
```

Если столбцы поменять местами (в А - начала диапазонов, В - группы) - неточный поиск с помощью *ВПР*:

```
=ВПР(1139;A1:B50;2)
```

Вместо искомого значения в формулу можно вписать ссылку на ячейку с этим значением.

Важно: значения начала диапазонов должны быть расположены в возрастающем порядке, первое значение - 0 (начало первого диапазона).

Comment: Больше нечего добавить. Работает. Спасибо.