# Вставка значения из Листа1 в Лист2

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

В экселе 2 листа. Первый - Имя, Дата рождения. И второй - Имя, Название школы.
Нужно вставить во второй лист год рождения из первого листа сравнив имена учеников.
Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, придерживайтесь [принятой практики в отношении приветствий](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7).

Comment: используйте функцию `ВПР`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения - использовать функцию `ВПР()`.
1. Имеем лист `Имя-ДтРождения` со столбцами `Имя`, `Дата рождения`. Каждому имени соответствует дата рождения. Обязательные условия для корректной работы функции `ВПР()` имена должны быть отсортированы в алфавитном порядке, имя должно быть уникально.

[image: Лист "Имя-ДтРожедния"]

2. Имеем лист `Имя-Школа` со столбцами `Имя`, `Школа`, `Дата рождения`. Значения для столбцов `Имя`, `Школа` определены.

[image: Лист "Имя-Школа"]

3. Для поиска по `Имени` значения даты рождения из листа `Имя-ДтРождения`используем функцию `ВПР()`. Для ячейки `С2` значение функции: `=ВПР(A2;'Имя-ДтРождения'!$A$2:$B$11;2;ЛОЖЬ)`

[image: Значение функции ВПР() для ячейки "С2"]

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение предыдущего ответа

> имена должны быть отсортированы в алфавитном порядке

Нет, не обязательно. Функция с интервальным просмотром *ЛОЖЬ(0)* ищет точное соответствие значения.

Сортировка нужна, если интервальный просмотр - *ИСТИНА(1)*. Это применимо в случаях, если, например, необходимо определить значение, принадлежащее диапазону.

Пример поиска по неточному соответствию:
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/375079/Формула-excel-или-как-выбрать-группу-значений/375087#375087](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/375079/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0-excel-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/375087#375087)

Если искомое значение находится правее извлекаемого, *ВПР* в обычной записи не справится. В этом случае можно использовать пару *ИНДЕКС/ПОИСКПОЗ*:

```
=ИНДЕКС(столбец_извлечения;ПОИСКПОЗ(искомое;столбец_поиска;))
```